# Finding file type or extension from inputstream - java 11

Tags: java, inputstream, java-11

I am making changes in legacy code where the method i am changing is getting inputstream from caller

```
public customObject getMyObject(InputStream is){

        String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(targetStream);
        System.out.println("file extens id  " + mimeType); // this gives null

}
```

Before I process the stream i want to detect if the content is from `CSV` or text. Some times clients upload wrong file.

If file is `.txt` i dont want to process it from my method or i want to process only csv file.

Is it possible to get `fileExtension` from `InputStream`

Comment: No. Whatever is calling "getMyObject" might know the file name, but a Java Stream knows has no concept of a "file name".

Comment: You could try Apache Tika to guess the content: https://tika.apache.org/. You'll have to process the content either way, though.

Comment: If only csv or txt are being sent, then I would check how csv-s are formatted, they mostly are comma (or other char) separated data, mostly same number of elements per row. If data matches such prediction then its probably csv, otherwise, its txt. But that is rather a hack, and will not always work - it should be fixed erlier in the process.

Comment: You could possibly just count the commas (all or on a few lines).   Statistically, I would think a csv file should have a lot more than an normal text file.

Comment: @PetrJaneček Tika (Lucene) is a totally different use case IMHO.
WJS What I said :-)
marcinj CSV is, by definition, "Comma" Separated Values. I know that sometimes they can be Tab separated, etc. but that is not really an "identifiable" attribute. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values